# Replace Xamarin.Forms Google Map API Key with custom string in separate file

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-manifest

Is there a way to replace the **API Key** from Xamarin.Forms Google Maps API with a *string/value* from a separate file?

Something like this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/apikey" />
```

Where the file is in `Resources > values > key.xml` and looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <string name="apikey">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</string>
</resources>
```

I've tried the above solution and it doesn't work. 
The reason I want to do this is that I **don't** want to commit my private key to Github, but I **do** want the repository to be public. That way I can exclude the key.xml file from commits instead of the whole AndroidManifest.xml file.

I've also realized you can replace that line from `AndroidManifest.xml` with this line of code in `AssemblyInfo.cs`

```
[assembly: MetaData("com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY", Value = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")]
```

but I still couldn't find any info on how to replace the string with a variable from a resource file.

Comment: You can access files on disk. So why not simply create a file like `secret.txt` which contains your secrets?

Comment: @MindSwipe How would I then implement strings from that file into the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Why do you need your API key inside the AndroidMannifext file?

Comment: @MindSwipe So you mean to import it into the AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: No. Read the text file once at startup of your app, and then use that API key to make calls to your API. There is not need to put it anywhere except your secrets file

Comment: @MindSwipe I still don't understand how to implement this.

Comment: use Secrets.cs static class-file *outside* your git folder, include this file in project *As Link*, keep your secrets there..

Answer (score 0):

So I found [this](https://github.com/rdelrosario/MapTrackingSample) git which uses the following method.
In `Constants.cs`

```
public static class Constants
    {
        public const string GoogleMapsApiKey= "--Add your google map api key here--";
    }
```

In `Android Folder > MainApplication.cs`

```
#if DEBUG
    [Application(Debuggable = true)]
#else
    [Application(Debuggable = false)]
#endif
    [MetaData("com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY",
              Value = Constants.GoogleMapsApiKey)]
```